# git add doesn't work on one folder

Tags: git

When I do

```
git add .
```

all files in my repository became under tracking excluding one folder named `java` that contains all my sources.
There is example:

```
git status

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   java/shadasviar (modified content, untracked content)

git add .
git status


Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   java/shadasviar (modified content, untracked content)
```

What can it be and how to resolve it?

Comment: Thats really strange, you already tried git add java/* ?

Comment: @jonathanrz, yes, I've tried add some concrete files frome subdirs of java/shadasviar/project/MainActivity.java, but there is no result neither, I've deleted .git folder and recreated it, but it hasen't helped

Comment: can you try with "git add -A"?

Comment: @jonathanrz, yes, no result

Comment: Can you try to use SourceTree? https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: @jonathanrz, I'm using linux) OpenSUSE 13.2. But if init repo in other level of folders, this folder adds normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting of all .git folders from all subdirectories helped.